# Can't direct access page from Google amp cache. Why?

Tags: amp-html

If searching on mobile, I'm getting our AMP pages in search results, and if I click on them, all is fine, pages are served off Google AMP cache.

But if I reload or directly try to enter the Google AMP cached URLs, I get a "Redirect Notice" page instead.

**Example:**

if directly opening https://www.google.com/amp/s/example.com/amp/page.html

I get: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://example.com/amp/page.html

Why is that happening?

Any way of getting that fixed?

Comment: use https://example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/example.com/amp/page.html Ref Link : https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/using_the_google_amp_cache/

Comment: @BachchaSingh thank you, but it still doesn't help when I refresh the already opened AMP page that is opened from mobile Google SERP

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/13659). Try to follow the instructions in this page https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/amp-cors-requests and check if Google amp cache has the updated version of page.